# PHP Lost value of foreach after if

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I lost my value in foreach after if

```
foreach ($etc_uloziste as  $id => $etc_id) {
    foreach ($etc_id as  $id2 => $etc_id2) {
        if($rodic1==$id) {
            if( ! in_array( $etc_id2, $etc_mn) ) { 
                //Check if the season already is displayed

                $sql.= ",\n"." ".$etc_id2."_id"." INT";

                $etc_mn[] = $etc_id2; //Store the season in the array
            }
        }
    }
}
```

before if I have value like:

```
[book] => Array
        (
            [0] => library
            [1] => room
        )
```

but after if is have only

```
[book] => Array
        (
            [0] => library
        )
```

the $etc_id2 is like library or room and $id is book

Comment: could you var_dump $etc_uloziste variable so we can look at it's structure? I got a feeling you are looping it the wrong way.

Comment: this is my $etc_ulozis  http://pastebin.com/zhZKsP1B

Comment: and what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: ` if($rodic1==$id) ` is going to drop all but one array item or all if the outer index exceeds the subarray count

Comment: if($rodic1==$id ia all true so how can i get next [1] => room
        )

Comment: What i want is get next value of [book] is    [1] => room

Comment: @user3492956 What is the value of `$rodic1` and `$etc_mn`?

Comment: $rodic1 is the index from foreach before this foreach like

Comment: anh $etc_mn isnt matter in here even i dont use my  this array i still lost the value of room it only go foreach in library

Answer (score 0):

I lost the value in 2. echo

```
 foreach ($result2 as  $rodic1 => $rodic_hodnot1)
            {           
             foreach ($etc_uloziste as  $id => $etc_id)
                    {                           
                                    foreach ($etc_id as  $id2 => $etc_id2)
                                     {                                  
                                        //echo $etc_id2."\n";                                
                                        if($rodic1 ==$id)
                                           {
                                             //echo $etc_id2."\n";                                              
                                            }                               
                                    }                                                                                                                                                                   
                    }
            }
```